# Need help in changing the dropdowns into range slider. Any help would be appreciated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to change this price range dropdown code into price range slider. Tried a lot but no luck. Can anyone help me in this?

```php
<div class="form-group">
   <select name="priceFrom" id="priceFrom" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">From</option>
         <?php for ($i=200000; $i <= 9000000; $i+=100000): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"<?php if ($_GET['priceFrom'] == $i) {
               echo ' selected';
            } ?>>$<?php echo $i; ?></option>
            <?php endfor; ?>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <select name="priceTo" id="priceTo" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">To</option>
      <?php for ($i=200000; $i <= 9000000; $i+=100000): ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"<?php if ($_GET['priceTo'] == $i) {
            echo ' selected';
         } ?>>$<?php echo $i; ?></option>
      <?php endfor; ?>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: PHP executes on the Server before anything is sent to the Browser. Once the page is in the Browser it's just seen as HTML. So, if you want a dynamic drop down to query something on the Server you should use a `change` Event and [FormData with the XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), otherwise you would have to do old school form submission which would reload the page *(nobody wants that)*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would refer you to a small tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".slider").change(function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    $(this).next(".value").html(v + "000000");
    if ($(this).is("#priceFrom")) {
      $("#priceTo").attr("min", v).val(v).trigger("change");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.form-group label {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>FROM</label> <input type="range" min="2" max="9" value="2" class="slider" id="priceFrom" /> <span class="value">2000000<span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>TO</label> <input type="range" min="2" max="9" value="2" class="slider" id="priceTo" /> <span class="value">2000000<span>
</div>
```

Here you can see the HTML and jQuery code working together to help adjust one or the other slider.

Comment: Hey @Twisty. Thank you for helping me in resolving this. I have implemented your code and while performing search, script doesn't pick up zeroes, script only picks single digit. Please see the URL -  ?action=filter_query&orderby=&priceFrom=2&priceTo=3. The url should be -  ?action=filter_query&orderby=&priceFrom=200000&priceTo=300000. Please hep me. Thanks

Comment: @WahedAliMohammed correct. You will want to adjust the math before the request or after in your PHP. I suspect you can find a way. Otherwise you can post a new question.

Comment: Hi Twisty. I tried but no luck. Can you help me in this? When I debug, i still see value of v to be single digit. Thank you mate.